# How to add a div and remove the same div on click

Tags: jquery

*edit*

Say my page is as follow

```
<div id="mask">content</div> 
<div id="box">content</div>
```

the div mask is hidden from the page.  How do I make it appear on click and hidden again when clicking on the same button.

either that or I could have

```
<div id="box">content</div> 
<div id="mask">content</div>
```

Both are visible on page but I want #mask to move back to before #box on click and then return to the original state on click again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
  $('#box').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).prev('#mask').length) {
       $(this).prev('#mask').toggle();
    } else {
      $(this).next('#mask').insertBefore(this);
    }
 });
 // code for mask hide on its click
 $('#mask').on('click', function() {
   $(this).hide();
 });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/bTVzb/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for the demo.  I will try this approach now.

Comment: It's working like I intended.  When I click on #box, #mask will appear before #box.  However, is it possible that when I click on #mask, it goes back to hidden?

Answer (score 0):

Keep a flag for the action you need. Something like this:

```
var flag='firstClick';
$('#box').on('click', function(){
    if (flag == 'firstClick') {
        $('#box').insertBefore($(this));
        flag = 'notFirstClick';
    }
    else $('#box').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to remove it if you just wanna hide it.
You can use

```
$("#mask").toggle()
```

on clicking of button. And place the mask div before the box div with `style="display:none"`

Comment: Can I know how to remove #mask after that?

Comment: `toggle()` will show in first call. then hide in next call. then again show in call... like wise. Do you still want to remove it?